# manually editing patches and debdiffs

Tags: debian, patch

I have a few debdiffs that were created, however, I'd like to apply a small change to all of them. The process of creating the debdiffs from scratch would be easy but very time-consuming.

Is manually editing debdiffs(just open via a text editor) a good practice or does it render debdiffs unusable? Is there a standard good-practice suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, if the debdiffs are submitted for patching stuff, hand-editing does not cause an issue.